# PHP elseif statement not executed even though initial if statement is false

Tags: php, recursion, control-flow

I am writing a recursive function to print out the differences between 2 multildimensional  php arrays.  The purpose of this code is to see the difference between jpeg headers to deteremine how adobe bridge cs3 is saving rating information within the jpg file.

When I am single-stepping through the code using my eclipse - zend debugger ide, it appears that even though the initial if statement is false (ie neither values is an array), the subsequent elseif statements are never executed.  The function is attached below.

Note:  Changes since original post based on comments
  Added a default level= ''
  Removed comments between the if{} elseif{} blocks
  Removed an else; at the end of the block that had no function 
  Encoded the < and > symbols so angle bracket would show in my code

```
function array_diff_multi($array1,$array2,$level=''){
  $keys = array_keys($array1);
  foreach($keys as $key)
  {
    $value1 = $array1[$key];
    if(array_key_exists($key,$array2) ){
      $value2 = $array2[$key];

      if (is_array($value1) && is_array($value2)){     // Check if they are both arrays, if so recursion is needed
        array_diff_multi($value1,$value2,$level . "[ " . $key . " ]");
      }
      elseif(is_array($value1) != is_array($value2)){  // Recursion is not needed, check if comparing an array to another type
        print "<br>" . $level . $key ."=>" . $value1 . "as array, compared to  ". $value2 ."<br>";
      }
      elseif($value1 != $value2){                      // the values don't match, print difference
        print "<br>" . $level . $key ."=>" . $value1 ." != " . $value2 ."<br>";
      }
    }
    else{                                              
      print "<br>" . $level. $key . "does not exist in array2";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the sample you're using for `$array1` and `$array2`

Comment: Maybe you misspoke - if both value1 and value2 are arrays the first if statement evaluates to true and the elseifs will be ignored...  The first elseif should trigger if one value is an array and the other is not, right?  Also, (I think) is_array will return true/false - so it's good practice to use "!==" instead of "!=".

Comment: yes, I did mistype.  I have corrected the example in the original question. The problem occurs in the second level of recursion comparing the first arrays ie item1[0][n] vs item2[0][n] where the value of both are now integers.

Comment: Josh - I get to the line with the original "if" then it jumps back to the top of the loop and compares the next items on the list.

Comment: thetaiko -  The arrays that I am using are very large.  They are the jpeg headers from image files and have at least 4 dimensions and many elements within the dimensions.  If I use print_r() to print the array it extends past the 32K length limit.

Comment: Does the elseif trigger as expected if recursion isn't required?  (Pass array1[0] as an array and array2[0] as an integer)

Comment: I'm confused, I think stackoverflow needs code line numbers.

Comment: epalla - I created 2 simple arrays<br>   $test3 = array(1,2,3);<br>
  $test1 = array(10,20,30);<br> and the elseif line was executed as expected.

Comment: Josh - The next item in the foreach loop gets executed.

Comment: Perhaps this is just my style, but (please?) get rid of the comments between the `}` and the `elseif`.  IMHO, it makes it REALLY hard to read... I prefer to have them on the same line, but I can understand different conventions...

Comment: I changed the comments location.  That is a good suggestion.  I also noticed that the angle brackets had to be replaced with the &gt; and &lt; to be properly displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me here.  I put your function (with the tiny difference of adding a default value of '' to the level parameter), and these two arrays:

```
$a1 = array('foo', 'bar', 2, array('baz', '3', 4, array(54,45)));
$a2 = array('faz', 'bar', 4, array('buz', '3', 5, 54));
```

And got this output:

```
0=>foo != faz

2=>2 != 4

[ 3 ]0=>baz != buz

[ 3 ]2=>4 != 5

[ 3 ]3=>Arrayas array, compared to  54
```

Perhaps your starting arrays are not what you think they are...?

Comment: Adding the default value was a good suggestion.  When I step through my code the $array1 variable continues to show the ORIGINAL array rather than the second level.  Do I need to do something different in php to pass the array by value?

Comment: Huh?  You mean `$level` shows the next level, but $array1 stays the same?  That shouldn't happen.  Is the code you posted above EXACTLY what you have?  If so, try disabling your debugger...  If not, update with the exact code (Because what you posted actually works fine)...

Comment: The debugger was behaving oddly.  I shutdown and restarted eclipse.  Now it appears that my code is working properly, but there is no difference between the arrays I was comparing!

Comment: I assumed that the metadata would be different between the 2 files, but apparently that is not the case.  In any case, we now have a useful function to quickly point out the difference between 2 multidimensional arrays.  Thanks for your help and the other expert's as well that pointed out formatting change suggestions and the use of a default value

Answer (score 2):

could it be because you have

```
else;
```

at the end...?

Try removing that or turning that into 'real code'

Comment: I removed the else; line.  The function still behaves the same way.  The problem occurs after it has launched the recursive function to start the comparison of the first arrays ie item1[0][n] vs item2[0][n] where the value of both are now integers.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think Adobe Bridge saves metadata in dotfiles in the same directory as the files. For example, sort information is saved in a `.bridgesort` file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Somehow the ratings I created in bridge are viewable in VISTA even though I don't copy the dot files to the new directory when I copy the jpg.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that all the `elseif`s would be skipped is if the two variables are not arrays and are equal.

Comment: I find it odd that even the first elseif isn't reached.  Is there something due to recursion is causing the odd behavior?  When I highlight the statement inside the first if statement it shows that the result is false (neither is an array), but the subsequent elseif is not reached.

Comment: But if neither of them is an array then the second `elseif` is false.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean the `&&` to be `||` instead?

Comment: Ignacio - I mistyped my example.  It has been corrected in the original question

Comment: The `if` does not check if *either* of them is an array, it checks if *both* of them are arrays. Your description does not match your code.

Comment: Ignacio - Comments in the code have been updated (edited) to clarify the intent